# Google Map V2 on Top half of the android screen and list view on the bottom half of the android screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I am working on a Android project in which I need to show `Google Map v2` on top half of the Android Screen and in the bottom half of the same android screen, I need to show a `ListView`.

Below is the code, I have so far which will be launched as soon as I launch my Application. I have setup properly the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for `Google Map V2 key`.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().hide();
        }
        findViewById(R.id.sample_button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources()
                                .getDisplayMetrics());
                        SlideoutActivity.prepare(SampleActivity.this,
                                R.id.inner_content, width);
                        startActivity(new Intent(SampleActivity.this,
                                MenuActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

And below is the `sample.xml file` which I need to modify so that I can add stuff which will have `Google Map v2` in top half of the android screen and in the bottom half, I will have `ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_android" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip"
        android:background="#bb000000">

        <Button style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
            android:id="@+id/sample_button"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text=">" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sample_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Facebook-like slide-out nav"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am done with all my settings related to setting up the Google Map API v2 key. I just need to plugin the code to start showing the google map v2 on the TOP half of the android screen and list view on the bottom half of the android screen.

Any help will be appreciated on this. Thanks

**Update:-**

Will this updated XML file will work to have Google Map v2 on top half of the android screen and ListView on bottom half of the android screen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_android" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="#bb000000"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sample_button"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:text=">" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sample_button"
            android:text="Proximity Application"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="19sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what problem you are facing to do this?

Comment: Problem is, I am not able to get the correct UI to have Google Map v2 on top half of the android screen and list view in the bottom half

Comment: Okay..see the answer posted by Emil Adz.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This layout should present you a map in the top half of the screen an a ListView in the bottom half:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list">          
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you should remove this xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" from fragment.

Comment: @Emil, with the above XML. I am getting this exception at the very end- `XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.` Any idea why is it so?

Comment: @Raghunandan, edited, the code block removed the last LinearLayout tag, Regarding your question this is the map namespace that will allow the user to use the map: properties. in case those properties are not used(as in this case), you are right this namespace can be removed, but it shouldn't interfere.

Comment: @EmilAdz i was about to do the same.

Comment: This code helped a lot. It worked as a charm. Placing the listview-LinearLayout above the map is not providing the expected output.